# DNSReports are talking about 2 SOA records

Tags: debian-wheezy, soa-record

I'm sorry to bother you. I'm actually losing my mind on my server's configuration.

For more information : I have a dedicated server from Kimsufi (OVH-lowcost :D) with Debian 7.1, and a few domains names from OVH.
I'm using BIND9 to set those domains/zones.

My principal domain is "vaeserveur.fr", which is also my server name. I'm saying this cause I'm beginning to think it could be a problem. (yes it's french as you can see)

So all my domains leads to vaeserveur.fr server, and their configuration seems ok.

In the other hand, **the DNS configuration about vaeserveur.fr does not seem ok**.
You can see by yourself here : https://intodns.com/vaeserveur.fr (for example)

```
Looks like your nameservers do not agree on the SOA serial. Ths SOA records as reported by your nameservers: 
91.121.166.194 ->  2017040410
213.186.33.199 ->  4135514717
This can cause some serious problems that is why you should fix this asap.
```

How the hell could it be 2 SOA records when I just set the vaeserveur.fr zone ?
(BTW, The second IP in the quote is the `ns.kimsufi.com` (secondary server from the registar).)

Don't hesitate to tell me what informations I could give you to help me, if it's ok for you.

Thx a lot...

Comment: One of your DNS servers isn't updating to the latest version of the zone - Theres only _one_ SOA for your zone, but multiple servers serving it, and they aren't serving the same thing.

Comment: Ok @pete, but how can I update the second DNS server as expected ? It's weird it is not automatically doing it. (Thx for your answer !!)

Comment: Is ns.kimsufi your server? Is it the master or slave? Is it configured properly with no errors?

Comment: ns.kimsufi is the "secondary dns server" from kimsufi, I guess I have no hand on it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it's easy to confirm that the two nameservers have zones where the `SOA` `SERIAL` values are wildly out of sync (indicating that their zone data is out of sync). The zone only has one `SOA` record in each case, but it doesn't match.

The `SOA` `SERIAL` is used to indicate which your version of the zone is, such as when slaves decide if they need to transfer (`IXFR`/`AXFR`) a new version from the master.

The serial number is defined in such a way that it endlessly wraps around, so it's not immediately intuitive how you compare values that are far apart or when you are near the max/min values. As an example, the range that is considered newer may continue into the lowest integers. You can read all the details in [rfc1982](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1982).

In this case, the value `4135514717` on the slave is near the end of what is considered greater compared to the serial `2017040410` on the master.
This means that the slave has a "newer version" according to the serial numbers and doesn't want the "older version" presented by the master.

If you have no direct control of the slave (ie, have no option to force it to get the current version), you will probably want to change the serial on the master to something that is greater than the current value on the slave. That way, it will accept the new version.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm gonna look into it. How the secondary dns server can have a different serial number ?

Comment: @Vae Normally a slave zone only briefly has a lower serial after a change has been made on the master side, then the current version is fetched and the serials then match until the next change.  As for how your serials ended up this way I can only speculate, presumably you have been changing the serial around in such a way that the slave ended up "stuck" with a newer serial. This does not occur if you steadily increment the serial value, as expected.

Comment: Kinda weird. As far as I know, I always use the YYYYMMDD## system for my serials. I send a ticket to Kimsufi's assistance but I guess I'l have to increase my SOA very hard.

Comment: @Vae If you always followed the pattern YYYYMMDDnn, there's no explanation where 4135514717 comes from. You and/or the service provider would have to have caused that somehow.

Comment: I guess so... A lot of thanks for you. I think I'll have to leave the usual SOA pattern, I'm kinda sad ! ^^

Comment: @Vae You can increment (keep rfc1982 in mind) it in a few steps, waiting for the slave(s) to sync up each time, to get back to where you were.

Comment: Oh, good to know ! I thought we could only increase it.... Once again, thx buddy. I was losing my mind, for something so... easy.

Comment: It looks like it fixes the whole thing. Thank you !